# UILabel: how do you set the font size?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do you set the font size from a `UILabel`?

My code:

```
UILabel *myView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:RectFrame];
[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[myView setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" A"]];
[myView setFont:[12] ]; <--- Error
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
[myView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
```

or

```
[myView setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
```

or for font family

```
[myView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
```

Answer (score 8):

If your `UILabel`'s font is defined in `IB` `storyboard` and you just want to increase size then this will work, worked for me ;)

```
[_label setFont: [_label.font fontWithSize: sizeYouWant]];
```

Or

```
[self.label setFont: [self.label.font fontWithSize: sizeYouWant]];
```

Another method as others says also worked:

```
[_label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0]];
```

Answer (score 6):

Check [UIFont](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. After that you'll probably get why you should use it like that:

```
[myView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
```

Answer (score 4):

Remember that the user can globally set how large they want their text to be, so you shouldn't use a fixed font size like "12". Use the following fonts:

```
[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline]

[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]
[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleSubheadline]
[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleFootnote]
[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleCaption1]
[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleCaption2]
```

I think the default for UILabel is Caption1, the others will be bigger or smaller. And they will adapt if the user wants big text or small text on his or her device. (Font size 12 might actually bigger than the normal label size if the user picked a very small size).

Answer (score 3):

```
UILabel *myView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:RectFrame];

[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[myView setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" A"]];

[myView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];

[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation?

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 and above.

You may also try it.

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

In swift

```
yourLabel.font = UIFont(name:"name of font-family you want", size: 9)
```