# App get crash while changing font

Tags: ios, uifont

This is how I change background of navigation bar and try to set font like this

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];        

UILabel *tmpTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 0, 100, 40)];
[tmpTitleLabel font:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];  
// APP CRASH (IF I ERASH THIS ABOVE LINE THEN TITLE GET DISPLAYED AS FACEBOOK )

tmpTitleLabel.text = @"Facebook";
tmpTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

tmpTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

CGRect applicationFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 40);
UIView * newView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame] autorelease];
[newView addSubview:imageView];
[newView addSubview:tmpTitleLabel];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:newView];
```

What am I doing wrong? I checked many answer but this is how they set font.

Comment: Strange. This gives me the compile time error: **No visible @interface for 'UILabel' declares the selector 'font:'** Your code won't even compile, then how can it crash ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[tmpTitleLabel font:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];`

This is wrong. You are using getter instead of setter. You missed the `set` part and capital `F`.

```
[tmpTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
               ^^^^
```

Or use dot syntax like this:

```
tmpTitleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294621/uilabel-how-do-you-set-the-font-size   i understand now, but i dont understand why 18 people gave   vote up here ?

Comment: you can see i am using in same way

Comment: @PrakashDesai the question you mentioned is about changing font size and somehow the answers, even the accepted one, missed the `setF` part. Please see that the question contained `setF` part correctly. Probably OP didn't notice that setter is not correct, probably he only noticed how to change the size.

Answer (score 2):

Assign font like this:

```
 tmpTitleLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
```

or use setFont: method

```
 [tmpTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
```